# My heuchera has acne!

Tags: identification, diseases

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I am not familiary with this plant disease but it sort of looks like the plan has acne.

The plant is a "Berry Smoothie" variety of heuchera, so the leaves are supposed to be pink. The weird red spots and the light colored bumps on the leaf undersides are what concerns me.

Top: 
[image: top]

Both sides:
[image: both]

Underside:
[image: underside]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the underside of the leaves please

Comment: Last photo is the underside of the leaf. I labeled the images to be a bit more clear.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? The underside of the leaves just looks lumpy - no sign of brownish rings under there?

Comment: Seattle, WA, USA. I don't see any brown rings

Answer (score 2):

I can see whitish deposits on the upper side of the leaf, particularly towards the centre of the leaf - might be eggs or something else, so its an infestation of some sort.

The only thing I know of that can cause bumps under the leaves and discoloration on top is rust (a fungal infection, which this isn't) and a spider mite infestation - but where you live, I wouldn't have thought it would have been  hot and dry enough for that in the last few weeks, though its possible you have other mites where you are that we don't have here.  http://thewhitepear.com/holly-blog/2013/5/2/spider-mites-heucheras

Comment: Hmm I was thinking the whitish stuff on top was pollen from the pine trees. We just got thru a major dump of pollen from them. How do you know it's not a fungal infection?

Comment: Because rust (which about the only fungal infection these are prone to) produces brown or rust coloured rings on the underside of the leaves, with faded, more or less circular spots on the top which eventually also turn brown. YOu might be right about the pollen, but best to get a magnifying glass and examine closely

Answer (score 1):

The bumps are scale - little insects sucking the sap from the plant.

We have a bunch of Q/As about treating them. Just search for them or click on: [scale](/questions/tagged/scale).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like some Eriophyes, If you look e.g. *Eriophyes vitis* on Google, you will find very similar galls in leaves. But that should be mainly on grape vines. So I think it is an other (but similar) Eriophyes.

On grapes, usually they do no cause much damages. It is one of the few insects that can be fight with a fungicide (sulfur based), but the best way it is not to fight it: antagonists will (hopefully) arrive (insecticide could kill them, so it is a trade off, check if the damages are increasing too much).

Answer (score 0):

It's Heuchera rust, Puccinia heucherae, due to damp weather, not enough airflow, overcrowding. It lives in the soil.

Originated on US Heucheras but getting increasingly frequent in the UK. Destroy affected plants but do not compost them. Keep soil clean of dead leaves, water in the morning and best not from above.

I've tried cutting off rusted leaves as they develop and taking root cuttings in the same situation but it still gets affected. I've had success moving a cutting to an open location in a pot and it hasn't rusted over 3 years, whereas the one in the border is regularly infected. It can infect other Heuchera nearby, though some varieties seem to be resistant.

I have 8 varieties in one massed area and only Heuchera Marmelade is affected here. In another area a different Heuchera is also infected, though I don't know what variety it is, whilst its neighbours, Silver Scrolls and Georgia Plum, have not succumbed.